# .preferredColorScheme(nil) visual bug when switching to system light / dark more

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a simple settings view for my MacOS app with a segmented picker for setting the light/dark/automatic(system) mode. It works just fine when switching between the dark and light modes, but when I set it to system (`.preferredColorScheme(nil)`), it looks like it initially colors half the app light and half dark. If I click again or click away, it all sets to the proper system mode. But it looks broken on initial selection:
[image]

Here's the picker from my settings view:

```
Picker("",selection: $userSettings.appearance) {
    Text("Automatic").tag(0)
    Text("Dark").tag(1)
    Text("Light").tag(2)
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
.labelsHidden()
```

It sets a value in my UserSettings:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("appearance") var appearance: Int = 0
    
    var selectedColorScheme: ColorScheme? {
        switch appearance {
        case 1:
            return .dark
        case 2:
            return .light
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

And then I set the actual mode on the outer-most view in my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var userSettings: UserSettings

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
        //stuff
        } detail: {
        //stuff
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(userSettings.selectedColorScheme)
}
```

I've also tried to set the `.preferredColorScheme` in the main app struct but it doesn't make a difference.

From the last comment in [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677212), I also got a sense that this could be a SwiftUI bug.

Comment: Have you found an answer/solution? I'm facing the exact same issue but on iOS.

Comment: @DmytroTitov I found a solution using AppKit instead of SwiftUI... You might have luck with UIKit for this (it actually turned out to be a cleaner solution with less lines of code). Apple actually rejected the app because of this bug originally even though I mentioned that it's likely their own bug.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! Do you have, by chance, an example of doing the same using UIKit? Perhaps you could even answer your own question 

Comment: what is solution for AppKit did you found?